# How to Use the WCF Service developed in .Net 4.0 in the Application developed in 2.0 or lower version?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I came across with this situation. I have one already developed Application in 2.0, Now in this application i want to use one WCF Service that is developed in 4.0. How can i do this?
I tried the following
1. Regular Method Add the Service Reference and then use that. It didn't work for me.
2. I googled it and i got one more method, using svcutil.exe, but i dont have svcutil.exe with 2.0.

Waiting for the response.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) was first introduced to the .NET Framework as part of .NET 3.0. It's not available with .NET 2.0.

If the WCF service exposes a SOAP endpoint then you may be able to use it through the Web Service Extensions (WSE) that were published for old versions of Visual Studio. See here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10854 for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a service written in .Net 4 with a .Net 2.0 project, you should be able to use basic http binding.  That should allow it to interop with a client that knows nothing about WCF.  It's similar to using an old school .asmx web service.